# Formula to return the number of nonblank cells in each row in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

|  |  |  |  | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | 4 |
| b | c |  |  | 2 |
| c | c | d |  | 3 |

[image]

Returns the number of nonblank cells in the range a1:d1 in c1. 
Returns the number of non-blank cells in the range a2:d2 in c2.
 Repeat for the ranges below in a similar way.

I was able to get the return value of one row using the formula, but I couldn't get it to return values for the rest of the rows. 
The formula I tried is as follows. 
 `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A:D,"<>"))` 
The problem with this formula is that it doesn't separate the rows in the range and sums all returned values.. 
How can I write a formula that gets the result of an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BYROW:

```
=BYROW(A1:D10,LAMBDA(row,IF(COUNTA(row)=0,,COUNTA(row))))
```